# switching view controllers by button click results in terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

Hi I am making an app and want to use a button to switch from one view controller to another view controller. I used a modal segue and made a `UIbutton` action calling `performSegueWithIdentifier`. However, I got

> Terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

error in AppleDelegate file. I have no idea what's going on here. PLease help me! THanks a lot.
Here is what the program explains:

```
2015-11-20 01:22:21.575 Photo book[17126:547637] Unknown class ViewController1 in Interface Builder file.
2015-11-20 01:22:21.581 Photo book[17126:547637] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIViewController 0x7f9698e1d2b0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key Open.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103d7fc65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000103a18bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103d7f8a9 -[NSException raise] + 9
    3   Foundation                          0x00000001035aeb53 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 259
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103cc7d50 -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 224
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010469252b -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1506
    6   UIKit                               0x00000001048f4aba -[UIStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:] + 181
    7   UIKit                               0x00000001048f80bf -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _perform:] + 71
    8   UIKit                               0x0000000111251638 -[UIViewControllerAccessibility performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:] + 39
    9   Photo book                          0x0000000103479c66 _TFC10Photo_book14ViewController5LoginfS0_FCSo8UIButtonT_ + 278
    10  Photo book                          0x0000000103479cea _TToFC10Photo_book14ViewController5LoginfS0_FCSo8UIButtonT_ + 58
    11  UIKit                               0x00000001043bbda2 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 75
    12  UIKit                               0x00000001044cd54a -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 467
    13  UIKit                               0x00000001044cc919 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 522
    14  UIKit                               0x0000000104408998 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 735
    15  UIKit                               0x00000001044092c2 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 682
    16  UIKit                               0x00000001043cf581 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 246
    17  UIKit                               0x00000001043dcd1c _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 18265
    18  UIKit                               0x00000001043b75dc _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 2066
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103cb3431 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103ca92fd __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 269
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103ca8934 __CFRunLoopRun + 868
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103ca8366 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    23  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001085cda3e GSEventRunModal + 161
    24  UIKit                               0x00000001043ba900 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    25  Photo book                          0x000000010348b1c7 main + 135
    26  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000106965145 start + 1
    27  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Answer (score 1):

this error occurs when you accidently delete iboutlet from your .h file but they are still connected in your xib or storyboard.. make sure that all your iboutlets are connected properly in your second view.

Answer (score 0):

First set you class name as following

[image]

Then set segue identifier

[image]

And check weather if you have deleted any `IBOutlet` accidentally or you have change name of controls programatically then respective outlet not found.